# File deletion with PHP: using basename() for defining relative url's of files

Tags: php, rename, unlink

I am trying to do two things with php:

1.move a pdf file to a new directory
2.delete an image

the info about the files that are stored in the sqldb are complete urls such as:

```
http://www.website.com/flyers/Fielding_306.pdf
```

so I am trying to use basename() to extract the file's name and then define the relative URL for moving or copying.

The folders: 
/0images/mod/ , /flyers and /flyers/archive  all have permissions set to 0777

The following script runs to completion while successfully deleting the row from sql and returning JSON encoded data back to the page, but the script **does not delete the files**. I am unsure where I went wrong.

```
    <?php
        $idc = $_POST["id"];        
    try {
        // cridentials
        require('../dbcon2.php');
        // connect to mysqli
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // statement to Retreive variables & execute
        $sqldf = "SELECT ad_link, listing_img FROM listings WHERE id=$idc";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqldf);
        $sdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $ad_link = $sdata["ad_link"];
        $img_link = $sdata["listing_img"]; 
      // 1. delete pdf file
        // get file name
        $file_link = basename($ad_link);
        // define file location
        $file_loc = '../flyers/'.$file_link;
        // define location to move file to
        $file_cop_loc = '../flyers/archive'.$file_link;
        // relocate file
        rename($file_loc, $file_cop_loc);

      // 2.delete image file
        // get image file name
        $pic_link = basename($img_link);
        // define current location as a relative reference
        $pic_loc = '../0images/mod/'.$pic_link;
        // remove image file
        unlink($pic_loc);

        // command to delete sql row
        $sqlda = "DELETE FROM listings WHERE id = $idc";

        //run 2nd query to delete sql row   
        mysqli_query($conn, $sqlda);

        // create a asociative array for a better control
        $data = array("success" => true, "idc" => $idc);

        // and you have to encode the data and also exit the code.
        exit(json_encode($data));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // create a asociative array
        $data = array("success" => false, "sentence" => $sql, "error" => $e.getMessage());
        // encode data and exit.
        exit(json_encode($data));
    }   
    ?>
```

Comment: `$ad_link` where is definited? look at http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: grrrrrrrrrrr I can't believe I forgot that ok I'm testing it

Comment: you should always enable `display_errors` to make an easier debug

Comment: still no luck but I'm sure that was needed :-) i'm adding it to the question

Comment: you don't get a couple of notice? `$result` isn't definited. :D `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqldf); $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`

Comment: Thank you, again. Still no luck now I'm getting weirded out

Comment: Did you get some errors? Put `var_dump($pic_loc,$file_loc, $file_cop_loc);` before `exit(json_encode($data));` for debug purpose

Comment: how do i see the var_dump in my browsers dev tool?

Comment: I'm probably gonna be on this till tmr

Comment: Just going through this question also. I noticed that `$listing_img` is also undefined for `$pic_link = basename($listing_img);`. In doing some backtracking, maybe you meant to use `$img_link` or `$ad_link` or `$file_link`? It's got to be one of those.

Comment: As for the `var_dump()`. Use it for all your variables to see what's being passed through or not. For example: `var_dump($img_link);` placed under `$img_link = $data["listing_img"];` and do the same for the other variables. You'll find it.